# Ads with script tags in template [Vue.js]

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, vue.js

In our project we've previously been using Thymeleaf, but now that we're moving over to Vue.js, we're experiencing some issues using the same ad scripts. The scripts look like this. I've only altered the URLs.

```
<script data-adfscript="sub.adcompany.net/asdf/?id=256746"></script>
<script src="//sub.adcompany.net/url/to/advertisement/script.js"  async="async" defer="defer"></script>
```

If we put these tags in the `<template>`, Webpack gives the following message:

> Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI.
>   Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as
>   , as they will not be parsed.

So I've then been Googling all over to find a similar case. There are some plugins that do this for Google Ads, but they won't work for us. Escaping the script tags `<\/script>` works in a way, but then the script isn't added to the DOM until *after* loaded, and so it doesn't run.

Has anyone run into similar issues? If so, what was your solution?

Vue file looks something like this:

```
<template>
  <aside class="sidebar-ad ui-wide">
    <script data-adfscript="sub.adcompany.net/asdf/?id=256746"></script>
    <script src="//sub.adcompany.net/url/to/advertisement/script.js"  async="async" defer="defer"></script>
  </aside>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Add those scripts in your index.html file

Comment: Yeah, I could do that, but then I'd have to write a script that moves the ad where I need it to be. Which I want to avoid.

Comment: ohk.. you have that implementation too...

Comment: Hey, did you ever get this to work? I'm in the same boat now and can't find a good solution to it.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I ended up putting the ad outside the Vue-code as I didn't have time or resources to continue the search for a good solution.

Answer (score 34):

There is a workaround. Works with `style` tag too.

```
<component is="script" src="https://www.example.com/example.js" async></component>
```

Comment: Thank God for you! I've been trying to find a good way to load Carbon Ads in Vue and this is more elegant than even the official Vue site does their own ads. This solution is beautiful.

Comment: That's hilarious! You just used this feature for a usecase I would never have thought of.  Top!

Comment: How it works and what it does? This answer is completely unclear if you are not familiar with Vue. I tried to use this line as is, and Vue shows me `error  Expected '<component>' elements to have 'v-bind:is' attribute`

Comment: The 'is' attribute is a part of HTML spec in the Custom Elements. Your issue seems to be eslint issue (hope you're familiar with these concepts). Try to make the attribute dynamic (":is='script'"), tweak your eslint config or open corresponding question.

Answer (score 9):

You should not treat Vue templates as a your final HTML, although their syntax is nearly identical and is also HTML-syntax compliant.

Templates are just a UI scaffolds for the data (that is why it is called a data-driven paradigm). They get parsed and transformed into render functions that in the end will produce the final and reactive DOM tree. During this process the `<script>` tags are indeed ommited cause it is not a place for any logic to happen.

**However if you really need to embed any 3rd party script within your component there is a neat way to do this.**

First, create container for the script:

```
<template>
    <div id="component-root">
        <!-- (...) -->
        <div v-el:script-holder></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then dynamicly create `<script>` tag and insert it directly to the DOM tree (using pure Vanilla JS):

```
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {};
        },
        ready() {
             let scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
             scriptEl.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.com/somescript.js');
             scriptEl.setAttribute('data-some-param', 'paramvalue');
             this.$els.scriptHolder.appendChild(scriptEl);
        },
    }
</script>
```

The `this.$els.scriptHolder` returns actual DOM element, calling the `appendChild()` forces the browser to insert DOM node and run the script just like during ordinary HTML code rendering.

Instead of `$els` you could also use `$el` which would return the components root DOM element (in this example the `<div id="component-root">`) or even the `$root.$el` which would return the Vue App root DOM element.

Note that `this.$els` is a Vue 1 feature, which has been replaced with `$refs` in Vue 2: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced

Comment: For the updated Vue 2 syntax, use the attribute `ref` instead: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced

Answer (score 6):

You can try with this package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-script2

Comment: It doesn't work with *single-file components* and *webpack* because it uses the `render()` function. I could rewrite the whole package to fit my project, but I was hoping I could avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

I made a vue component to handle script loading within the template tags.

Personally, I use it to load ads in my vuejs apps.

here:

https://github.com/TheDynomike/vue-script-component

Comment: I used this and it was super helpful. It also worked with my single file components.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to work around this, not sure how well it works but this the way I did it.

Run the `<script>` in normal html then go to Dev tools and copy the iframe code made by the script and then paste it into the code as iframe instead of the `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

just place your in vue template scripts after your app, in exemple at the end of the body

```
(function($) {
            $('#your-app').find('script').appendTo('body')
            <script> your vue script (create app)</script>
    })(jQuery);
```