# Vue js is deleting a script tag when compiled

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm new with Vue.js and I'm having an issue that I can not solve.. I'm using Vue cli 3 and in my code I'm adding a custom tag (not a component) on my template with a script tag inside.

```
<ra type="outstream" pid="888666574" ra_init="open" ra_end="open" skin="dark" hasConsent="1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s.test.com/script.js"></script>
</ra>
```

This script goes to search the custom tag ra, so needs to be inside of the tag. The problem is that when I inspect the site with devTools, the ra tag is empty. I mean, the script it's not there. I think that maybe Vue is removing the script to prevent  XSS or something like that, but I need to run this script.

Someone knows what's happening?

Thanks! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561612/ads-with-script-tags-in-template-vue-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mounted() {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('src', 'https://s.test.com/script.js');

  let wrapper = document.createElement('ra');
  wrapper.appendChild(script);
  wrapper.setAttribute('pid','888666574');
  wrapper.setAttribute('ra_init','open');
  wrapper.setAttribute('ra_end','open');
  wrapper.setAttribute('skin','dark');
  wrapper.setAttribute('hasConsent','1');
  document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

Try this i hope it helps

Comment: I think that this could work. The problem is that I need to call this after an ajax call, and I need to set a variable with the response, so the script will take this var. Could work with the mounted function?

Comment: try to add it in a custom function and call this function on success of the ajax call. I think it will do the trick but to be honest i have never tried it

Comment: you mean add this code that you write in a function and call it when it's mounted and after the ajax call?

Comment: no you add this code instead of the mounted hook to a method. When you want to add this to the dom you call that method. In your case when the ajax call finish

Comment: and it will execute the script? Because I tried it as you said and the script now appears in the DOM, but it's not been executed

Answer (score -1):

Just embed script tags in template tag. So VueJs don't delete these script tags

```
<template>
    <script></script>
</template>
```