# Running <script> tags within <template> on vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I've run into a problem whilst adding a Iframe that a service I am using has given me. They come in  tags. I am using Vue 3 as a framework so when I insert them into the  I get an error.

I've tried searching for a solution but the only thing that I've been able to find is this, [Ads with script tags in template [Vue.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561612/ads-with-script-tags-in-template-vue-js). However it is from 2017 and even the solutions posted on there are outdated and do not work.

```
<script src="//widget.xxxxxx.it/v2/widget/widget.js"></script>
<script>var widget = new SimplybookWidget({"widget_type":"iframe","url":"https:\/\/xxxxxxx.simplybook.it","theme":"dainty","theme_settings":{"timeline_show_end_time":"1","timeline_hide_unavailable":"1","hide_past_days":"0","sb_base_color":"#13445b","secondary_color":"#e4ebf5","sb_text_color":"#13445b","display_item_mode":"block","body_bg_color":"#fefbe9","sb_background_image":"","sb_review_image":"","dark_font_color":"#13445b","light_font_color":"#ffffff","sb_company_label_color":"#ffffff","sb_cancellation_color":"#ff7a93","hide_img_mode":"0"},"timeline":"modern","datepicker":"top_calendar","is_rtl":false,"app_config":{"allow_switch_to_ada":0,"predefined":[]}});</script>
```

The error...

```
VueCompilerError: Tags with side effect (<script> and <style>) are 
ignored in client component templates.
```

Comment: please add the error you get

Comment: Is that the full widget code or is there a html element accompanied

Comment: Normally when I put inside of normal html it works directly, however when I do it in vue it doesn't work. I wrap everything inside of <template><div><script</script></div></template> but vue doesn't like that...

Answer (score 2):

In Vue it generally is not possible to use *script*-tags within the *template*-tags.

Instead of using *script*-tags in HTML, use **mounted()** to add your JavaScript code to Vue's JavaScript section.

You can find extensive examples [here](https://vue-view.com/how-to-load-an-external-script-in-vue-component/).

Answer (score 0):

If there is no html elements accompanied you can move this to your own script section e.g.

This may not be required and you can do it another way, e.g. just download it and load it yourself.

```
npm install require-from-url
```

```
var requireFromUrl = require('require-from-url/sync');
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            widget: null,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        var SimplybookWidget = requireFromUrl("//widget.xxxxxx.it/v2/widget/widget.js");
        this.widget = new SimplybookWidget({"widget_type":"iframe","url":"https:\/\/xxxxxxx.simplybook.it","theme":"dainty","theme_settings":{"timeline_show_end_time":"1","timeline_hide_unavailable":"1","hide_past_days":"0","sb_base_color":"#13445b","secondary_color":"#e4ebf5","sb_text_color":"#13445b","display_item_mode":"block","body_bg_color":"#fefbe9","sb_background_image":"","sb_review_image":"","dark_font_color":"#13445b","light_font_color":"#ffffff","sb_company_label_color":"#ffffff","sb_cancellation_color":"#ff7a93","hide_img_mode":"0"},"timeline":"modern","datepicker":"top_calendar","is_rtl":false,"app_config":{"allow_switch_to_ada":0,"predefined":[]}});
    },
    destroyed() {
        this.widget = null;
    },
}
```

Comment: I guess I suck at explaining haha, my bad. I've found a solution on my own I think however I don't know how well it will work in the future. I copied the <iframe> tag that the code generated and pasted directly into the <template> it works will see if any issues come up, thanks for your help tho.

Comment: Na the issue is that you can never use <script> inside vue. its not meant to be used that way, its like using jquery and vue. you have to take the script code and use it inside the vue templates. your solution works for now however it may fail in future. by this i mean no using <script> inside the `id="app"` of your application.

Comment: Is there any work around that you know of?

Comment: Yeah by moving the code inside the script tags to the actual vue application code. like i've done above then recompiling your app.

Comment: And what would the html element look like?

Comment: I've managed to make  the component work with the way you told me, however now when I click to another tab on the navbar it doesn't switch over just keeps showing same page but the route still changes..

Comment: @DMantas you will want to use the `destroyed` method on the component and kill the script